# flux / react: how to handle filtered api-data in a store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, flux, reactjs-flux

I created an app which uses the flux pattern and pulls data from an API. 
This is updating data how it works now:

1. Component calls the `get()` action
2. The action pulls data from an API
3. The action dispatches a storechange event to the related store containing the new data
4. The store updates its state with the received payload from the action and emits a viewchange event
5. The component listens to the viewchange event, pulls the new items from the store and re-renders

This is working fine so far. But now I wonder how I would do filtering. E.g. for a specific component ("Notifications") I only want to return the unread notifications, or the notifications in a given time-period. 
When I implement an action `getByStatus(status)` `getByDate(start, end)`, the whole store would only contain unread notifications or the ones in the time period, which is a problem when you want to show all notifications and the unread ones at the same time.

Is the only way to do this to create a filter-method with javascript / lodash or similiar? This would make any filtering on the server side obsolete and cause a lot of (uneeded) traffic. 
And creating separate stores like "UnreadNotificationStore" would be pretty annyoing to handle, and in case of the time period the problem would still exist. 
The only way I can think of is to add the  `getByStatus(status)` action without updating the store, and returning the data directly to the component.

Comment: Have you tried `.filter` function ? like `this.getState().filter( element => element.color !== "blue")`

Comment: Having the same issue as you, and still looking for a solution. To clarify: the filtering happens **server side**, and this means that when the server returns filtered data, that data is *all there is going to be in the store*, which is where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually talking about filtering items down from a payload that you already have in memory client-side, or do you need to do a new fetch from the server for those "filters"?

If just filtering client-side:

1. Store all fetched items in something like a `collection` branch of your store.
2. Dispatch your filter choice and store that in a `filter` variable.
3. Filter your `collection` using something like that `.filter` method that @cley suggested, and store the filtered ids in a `filteredCollection` variable.
4. Add a getter to your store like `getFilteredItems` that returns your filtered ids mapped to the full records in `collection`.

If fetching each time from the server:

1. Same as above but store the full items in `filteredCollection` rather than just the ids. (Unless you are going to end up with lots of data in memory, in which case you can consider maintaining a single collection that you augment with each fetch from the server and then filter from, but this adds a good bit of complexity that I wouldn't recommend unless you're certain you'll have memory issues.)

There are a number of other possibilities, but this is a reasonable place to start.